# How to filter grouped records in Extjs's grid?

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs4, grouping, extjs-grid

I would like to group records and then filter them. When the code below is executed the records are grouped and during the loading of the grid, I can see the records being filtered by the condition, however, when the loading is finished, all (unfiltered) records are displayed.

Is there any way to make this work as expected?

Code:

```
  afterrender: function(){
                var myStore = this.myStore;
                myStore. load({
                    callback: function(records, operation, success){
                       myStore.group('status', 'DESC');
                        if(recID != 0){
                            myStore.filterBy(function(record){
                                return record.get('count') > '10' ;
                            });
                          }
                       }
                    });
                  }
```

Comment: The code smells really fishy. Where do you get `recID`, do your records really have a `count` property, and why do you compare against a string? Can you make a fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @Alexander, recID is a shared record, however my issue got resolved by having two events for the grid: render and afterrender, in the first one I filtered the records by condition, and in the second one I grouped the (filtered) records.